# Origins of the term "עולם השקר"

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

What are the earliest sources referring to our world as "עולם השקר"?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.org/question/278732

Answer (score 4):

The terms עוֹלָם דְּשֶׁקֶר for this world and עוֹלָם דְּקוּשְׁטָא for the next world appear in [Vayikra Rabba 26:7](https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Vayikra_Rabbah_26:7) (Samuel raised from the dead is speaking to Saul):

> כַּד הֲוֵינָא גַּבָּךְ הֲוֵינָא בְּעוֹלָם דְּשֶׁקֶר, וַהֲוֵית שְׁמִיעַ מִנִי מִלִּין שִׁקְרִין דַּהֲוֵינָא דָחֵיל מִנָּךְ דְּלָא תִקְטֵילוּנְנִי, וְכַדּוּן דַּאֲנָא בְּעוֹלָם דְּקוּשְׁטָא לֵית אַתְּ שְׁמִיעַ מִנִּי אֶלָּא מִלִּין דִּקְשׁוֹט
>
> When I was with you I was in the false world and you heard false things from me because I was afraid of you killing me ["someone better than you" will take your place as king]. Now that I am in the true world, you will hear from me nothing but truth [David will take your place as king].

Answer (score 3):

While the phrasing is not identical, it's possible that [Pesachim 50a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.50a.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) (and Bava Basra 10b) is an early source for this idea. In this passage, the gemara mentions עוֹלָם הָפוּךְ, "inverted world", which seems to be the same concept:

> וְרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי אָמַר: אֵלּוּ בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁיְּקָרִין
> הֵן בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וּקְפוּיִין הֵן לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. כִּי הָא דְּרַב
> יוֹסֵף בְּרֵיהּ דְּרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי חֲלַשׁ וְאִיתְנְגִיד,
> כִּי הֲדַר, אֲמַר לֵיהּ אֲבוּהּ: מַאי חֲזֵית? אֲמַר לֵיהּ: *עוֹלָם
> הָפוּךְ רָאִיתִי*, עֶלְיוֹנִים לְמַטָּה, וְתַחְתּוֹנִים לְמַעְלָה.
> *אָמַר לוֹ: בְּנִי, עוֹלָם בָּרוּר רָאִיתָ*. וַאֲנַן הֵיכִי הָתָם? כִּי
> הֵיכִי דְּאִיתוּ אֲנַן הָכָא, הָכִי אִיתִינַן הָתָם. ‏

> And Rabbi
> Yehoshua ben Levi said: These are people who are considered important
> [yekarim] in this world and unimportant [kefuyim] in the
> World-to-Come. This is like the incident involving Rav Yosef, son of
> Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi, who became ill and was about to expire. When
> he returned to good health, his father said to him: What did you see
> when you were about to die? He said to him: *I saw an inverted world.*
> Those above, i.e., those who are considered important in this world,
> were below, insignificant, while those below, i.e., those who are
> insignificant in this world, were above. *He said to him: My son, you
> have seen a clear world. The world you have seen is the true world*, as
> in that world people’s standings befit them. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi
> asked: And where are we, the Torah scholars, there? Rav Yosef
> responded: Just as we are regarded here, so are we regarded there.

[Text and translation taken from Sefaria. The translation used is the William Davidson (Koren - Steinsaltz) edition. Italics added.]

For what it's worth, the Hebrew version of [Rav Steinsaltz's commentary ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.50a.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=he) reiterates the framing of "עולם האמת" as the opposite of our world, so this might be it.

> **אמר לו: בני, עולם ברור ראית.** *שהעולם שראית הוא הוא עולם האמת*, ובו
> היחסים בין הבריות הם כראוי להם.‏

[Bold in original, italics added.]

I could not find the exact phrase "עולם השקר" or "עולם שקר" in the Talmud with a cursory search on Sefaria.

Comment: Not going to go for עולם הפוך? Right there in that sugya. I think that's basically a synonym for עולם השקר. Also found in Bava Batra 10b

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, @RabbiKaii? The words עולם הפוך are right there in my answer, and italicized as well.... Is there something missing that I didn't already write about?

Comment: You didn't specifically refer to it, that's all, just "עולם ברור" and Steinsaltz on that. I am probably being too picky, sorry, I just felt the answer would have had more impact if you had outrightly made עולם הפוך the emphasis

Comment: I thought that the italicization would be enough emphasis, but I could be wrong! It's definitely believable that it's tough to see that Hebrew italicization in some fonts.... Tell you what @RabbiKaii, if you see a way to make that point even clearer, go ahead and edit the answer. (On the off chance that I think you've made things worse, I'll revert the change later.)